# Trouble Connecting Zabbix to Zapier with a Webhook

Tags: javascript, https, webhooks, zabbix, zapier

I'm fairly new to Zabbix and I've been trying for the past couple days to set up a webhook from Zabbix to Zapier. I understand that I'm probably making a fairly juvenile error and I don't expect you to solve the problem for me, but I would appreciate it if another more experienced user could push me in the right direction.

I'll add screenshots of my script and settings, as well as the errors I'm getting when I try and test it. If anyone is familiar connecting Zabbix to Zapier, or Zabbix to another similar application, I would greatly appreciate your input. Let me know if you need any additional information.

##### Zabbix Media Type Config

[image: Zabbix Media Type Config]

##### Zabbix Script

[image: Zabbix Script]

##### Zabbix Test Config

[image: Zabbix Test Config]

##### Zabbix Test Errors

[image: Zabbix Test Errors]

Comment: Error "couldn't resolve hostname" means your host cannot connect to that URL. Try the same test on the command line.